# Using Django to filter object values of an attribute based on user-selected values of another object attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, database-design, django-orm

I have 3 tables which are item, shop and stock

```
item table consists of 
item_id    item_name     item_price
1          drug AJG         32.00
2          drug BOLS        10.00 
3          drug CPP         5.00
4          drug C77         55.00
5          drug CLIMO       13.00 

shop table consists of
shop_id    shop_name       shop_country
3          ABC Clinic      Australia
4          FYZ Hospital    New Zealand
5          HH Pharmacy     Spain
22         SAJ Clinic      Portugal
33         PO Pharmacy     Portugal

stock table consists of
shop_id    item_id     stock_qty
3          1           22  
4          2           45 
5          3           11
22         4           39
33         5           66
```

I've built  web app using Django to allow the user to input the item_name (i.e., Drug A) and shop_name (ABC Clinic) using the following code. So far, i have a function that is able to show the item names and shop names based on regex. However, the results rendered also show combinations where the shop does not have that particular item. For example, the results.html page will show ABC clinic with Drug CLIMO stock if the user keys in Climo for item and ABC for shop - even though ABC clinic does not have that drug.

As such, is there some way Django can display the shops that only have stock of the item that was selected? To filter the item_name and the shop_name, there is a need for the stock table to be joined to the shop table (using shop_id) and the stock table to be joined to the item table (using item_id)

Also, is there a way to do this using javascript? any form of help or guidance is much appreciated.

```
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.db import connection
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Shop, Stock, Item # import models
from django.http import HttpResponse


def getresult(request):
#Renders the results page allowing users to select the shop and item    
    if request.method == 'GET':
    # values sent via GET by the user
        shop_name = request.GET.get('regex_shop','')
        item_name = request.GET.get('regex_item','')
 
        shop_results = Shop.objects.filter(s_name__contains = shop_name).values()
        item_results = Item.objects.filter(i_name__contains = item_name).values()
        
        result = {'s_records': shop_results, 'i_records': item_results}
        return render(request,'AppInventory/results.html',result)
```

The models.py is below if it helps

```
from django.db import models

i__con
class Item(models.Model):
    i_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    i_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    i_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'item'


class Stock(models.Model):
    s = models.OneToOneField('Shop', models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    i = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING)
    s_qty = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stock'
        unique_together = (('s', 'i'),)


class Shop(models.Model):
    s_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    s_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    s_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shop'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the item_results to get the item_id

```
for each_result in item_results:
    id = each_result['id']
```

Next use the "id" to check the stock table and get the "shop_id" and finally you can find the shop by the "shop_id":

```
Shop.objects.get(shop_id=shop_id)
```

There might be easier solution if there is some kind of relation in the models but I would need the models.py code for this.

Comment: the models.py has been added. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, you would need to set a related_name attribute:

related_name="orders"

Comment: Yes, you would need to set a related_name attribute:

i = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="stock_items")

Once this is set you can access and query Stock table:

item_name = request.GET.get('regex_item','')

item_name.stock_items.filter(s_qty__gte=0)

By  the "stock_items" reverse relation you are accessing all Stock objects which belong to the Item object and then you filter the "s_qty" field by gte(greater than or equal). Note that there is double underscore between them as this is how they should be declared.